# MYSQL SUM in a left join query (two tables)

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

thanks for looking at my issue. I have been researching quite a lot of material on StackOF and I came up with this.

I have two tables, one with customers (accounts) and one with a list of opportunities. I would need to get a list of *all* accounts alongside a SUM() of all the opportunities linked to them.

As an example of result:

```
Account      Responsible     Opportunities
Customer 1   John Doe        0
Customer 2   Roy Depp        500
Customer 3   Carl Popper     1500
```

The way I relate the two tables is that every account has a unique id, and in the opportunities table, each line/opportunity (while having a unique opportunity id) will also carry the account id.

After quite a lot of research, here is the query I managed to write so far:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`,  `a`.`name`, `responsible`, `city`, `postcode`, `tot`.`amounto` 
FROM `accounts` AS `a` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `accountID`, SUM(`amount`) AS `amounto` 
           FROM `opportunities` 
           GROUP BY `opportunities`.`accountID`) AS `tot` 
    ON `a`.`id` = `tot`.`accountid` 
WHERE `postcode` = '2000' 
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
```

The query is successful, however the SUM (amounto column) is always NULL. Can some MySQL guru please explain what am I doing wrong? :-)

Thanks in advance and cheers from Sydney, Australia!

Comment: Works fine for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f95aea/1. The only explanation is that none of the accounts with that postcode have any opportunities.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your prompt answer! I am using a test database, so that could be the reason (though I have 1,500+ records in either table, so..). But I will definitely check and come back if it doesn't work. (BTW, love SQL fiddle!) :-) Thanks again!